# Strange behaviour with apex:variable using rendered condition

Tags: apex, visualforce

We are trying to use a `apex:variable` in the `rendered` attribute inside a `apex:commandlink`. The issue is that the var value can not be readable by the rendered attribute (for reasons unknown to me). Using the next code everything seems fine, the text 'MORE' is showed but the **action method is not called**.

I have tried to compare the var `moreArticlesToShow` with `null` value and it is working, the method is called but it is not enough because I need to show the link only when it is equals to true.

```
<apex:variable var="moreArticlesToShow" value="false" />

<apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="knowledgeContent">

  <knowledge:articleList articleVar="article"
                         hasMoreVar="hasMoreArticles"
                         pageSize="3"
                         pageNumber="{!counter}"
                         articleTypes="{!knowledgeArticle}"
                         language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.language))}">

      <apex:variable var="moreArticlesToShow" value="{!hasMoreArticles}" />
  </knowledge:articleList>

  <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
      <apex:commandLink action="{!increment}" rendered="{!moreArticlesToShow}" value="MORE"
                        reRender="knowledgeContent" status="actStatusSubmitButton"/>
  </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:outputPanel>
```

Finally, I use the same var in a `apex:outputtext` and surprisingly the same variable is working perfectly and the text is showed only when the value is true

```
<apex:outputtext value="MORE" rendered="{!moreArticlesToShow}" />
```

Why is different the behaviour between both tags? and How can I solve it?